# While loop with logical operators - stuck in loop

Tags: c#, while-loop

I want "Y" or "N" to be the only valid input, which I did like this:

```csharp
Console.WriteLine("Connect to the Database? Y/N");
string answer = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
while (answer != "Y" || answer != "N")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Incorrect Response.");
    Console.WriteLine("Connect to the Database? Y/N");
    answer = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
}
if (answer == "N") Environment.Exit(0);

Console.WriteLine("Successfull connection!");
```

But, whatever I enter as the answer, including "Y" and "N", it just loops forever.

Comment: Please edit your question and add a language tag corresponding to the programming language you are using. Otherwise the question is impossible to answer and will not be found by those who can answer it.

Comment: Should be `answer != "Y" && answer != "N"`. Your current condition is always true.

Comment: As it stands one of these `answer != "Y" || answer != "N"` is always true (+1 `@bbbbbbbbb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While saying `answer != "Y" || answer != "N"` you are telling C# that if at any case, answer is not equal to that, it will continue to prompt the user.
Following that logic, if answer is Y, then it is not equal to N. And in the other way, if answer is N, it is not equal to Y.
That means that in order to work, it should not be equal to Y AND to N.

```
Console.WriteLine("Connect to the Database? Y/N");
string answer = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
Console.WriteLine(answer != "Y");
Console.WriteLine(answer != "N");
while (answer != "Y" && answer != "N")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Incorrect Response.");
    Console.WriteLine("Connect to the Database? Y/N");
    answer = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
}
if (answer == "N") Environment.Exit(0);

Console.WriteLine("Successfull connection!");
```